# How can I prevent a Textfield that's in line with text from cutting into words?

Tags: latex, textfield, hyperref

I'm using hyperref Textfields to create a fillable pdf with fields inline with the text. I'm getting strange clipping around the Textfield boxes. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsem 
\TextField[name=name,width=5cm,charsize=16pt] 
dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I was missing the label argument for the Textfield.  In this case, I don't want to use a label so empty curly brackets suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsem 
\TextField[name=name,width=5cm,charsize=16pt]{}
dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]